# edit a program on IBM Q experience

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

Can I edit a program with python numpy and scipy and of course qiskit in the IBM Q experience, using code? (I am not interested in drugging gates) and I can't find the way to edit my own program

Answer (score 2):

You can't edit using python in the circuit composer. You can edit the `OpenQASM` which can be found on the left-hand side of the composer.

If you would like to use Qiskit, this is also available through the Q Experience, you need to click on the Jupyter Notebooks. Here you can create circuits of your own, or modify the given examples.